# Getting number of errors in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an error in stored procedure as follows:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure K2_CHECKENTRYINFILELOG, Line 27
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure K2_CHECKENTRYINFILELOG, Line 42
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure K2_CHECKENTRYINFILELOG, Line 55
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure K2_CHECKENTRYINFILELOG, Line 58
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure K2_CHECKENTRYINFILELOG, Line 61
>   Incorrect syntax near 'end'.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K2_CHECKENTRYINFILELOG] 
   @FILENAME VARCHAR(150),
   @FILEPATH VARCHAR(MAX),
   @FILETYPE int,
   @FILEDATE datetime,
   @CIRCLEID INT,
   @TOTALROWS int,
   @SUCCESSCOUNT int,
   @FAILURECOUNT int,
   @PROCESSED bit,
   @ERROR varchar(MAX),
   @VENDORID int,
   @CREATEDBY INT = 1,
   @CREATEDON DATETIME,
   @DELETED BIT=0
   --@FILELOGID BIGINT OUTPUT
if  
begin
   select count(CIRCLEID) as CircleId 
   from K2FILELOG 
   where FILEPATH = @FILEPATH 
     and [FILENAME] = @FILENAME 
     and FILETYPE = @FILETYPE 
     and FILEDATE = @FILEDATE 
     and CIRCLEID = @CIRCLEID 
     and TOTALROWS = @TOTALROWS 
     and SUCCESSCOUNT = @SUCCESSCOUNT 
     and FAILURECOUNT = @FAILURECOUNT 
     and PROCESSED = @PROCESSED 
     and ERROR = @ERROR 
     and VENDORID = @VENDORID 
     and CREATEDBY = @CREATEDBY 
     and CREATEDON = @CREATEDON 
     and  DELETED = @DELETED > 0
begin
if 
   begin
      select count (CIRCLEID) as CircleId 
      from K2FILELOG with (nolock) 
      where FILETYPE = @FILETYPE 
        and [FILENAME] = @FILENAME 
        and FILEPATH = @FILEPATH  
        and FILEDATE = @FILEDATE 
        and CIRCLEID = @CIRCLEID 
      GROUP BY 
        CIRCLEID 
      having 
        count(CIRCLEID) >= 4

    return 1;
end
else 
    return 0;
END
ELSE If
begin
    return o;
end
```

Kindly help me please.

Thanks in advance

Harshal

Comment: Well, you need `AS` after the list of parameters, for starters. Also good to enclose the body of the procedure in `BEGIN` and `END` (more for visual aesthetics than anything).

Answer (score 4):

It is telling you there are syntax errors in your procedure, and there are.

I can't quite tell what you are trying to do as the syntax is pretty odd...

The first error refers to having an `IF` statement with no test clause. These should be of the form `IF <condition> <statement>` or `IF <condition> BEGIN <statetments> END` - having no condition (the `BEGIN` directly following the `IF`) simply isn't valid syntax.

The next is referring to `DELETED = @DELETED >0` which again simply isn't valid syntax in TSQL. If you are trying to set the value for the output `DELETED` to true if the variable `@DELETED` is greater than zero the you want something like `DELETED = CASE WHEN @DELETED>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` or to make sure that the output value type is boolean `DELETED = CAST(CASE WHEN @DELETED>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)`.

I'll not go through each error as that syntax is so far "off" that I can't tell what you are actually trying to achieve and you've not described the intended process at all. I suggest that you read up on TSQL syntax.

Comment: I want to prove this condition as follows.1 st Condition :If i found the same record in database,it should not save the Record and return 1.
2 nd Condition:if i found more than 4 record for the same CircleId it should not allow to save and return 1.So in my stored procedure I want to check for if exists for both the condition ,but i am confused to implement it that's why i have taken help from your team .Please guide me in my stored procedure.Please tell me what changes i need to do.please David help me out Thanks in advance Harshal

Comment: You also have a return o at the end instead of a return 0.